# Move files within directories and subdirectories to an entirely new directory

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, command-line-interface

I have logo files that are in the Downloads folder and a folder within the downloads folder

I'm am in the Users/name/Downloads/Subfolder directory and want to move all the files that have a certain keyword IN the /Downloads AND /Downloads/Subfolder to a new directory in: Users/Name/NewDirectory/Pictures but only the files with the keyword in /Downloads/ moved, not the ones in Users/Name/Downloads/Subfolder

I tried (w/ caps on purpose):

```
mv *Keyword*.jpg ../../NewDirectory/Pictures/
```

I was expecting ALL the files with the keyword to be in Users/Name/NewDirectory/Pictures/. I checked with

```
find . -iname "*Keyword*"
```

And there were still files in the Users/Name/NewDirectory/Pictures/Subfolder directory.

Is there an option that I should use when moving them? (-i? -r? -R?, pls let me know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following two solutions:

```
find . -name *Keyword*.jpg -exec mv {} ../../NewDirectory/Pictures/ \;


find . -name *Keyword*.jpg -print | xargs mv ../../NewDirectory/Pictures/
```

Comment: I've resolved it now, but thank you a lot. Please, what does "-exec" and the curly braces do?

Comment: -exec executes the command which follows and the curly braces basically contains the output of what found is finding (in this case the matching files)